# How to make mdc fields indexed or analyzed in logstash with elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, log4j, logstash, mdc

I use SocketAppender to report log events to logstash which connect to elasticsearch.
I record some application context info by using MDC. I hope to filter events by MDC fields.
How to make  mdc fields indexed or analyzed in logstash with elasticsearch?

for example:
I write : `MDC.put("email", "11111@example.com")` in my java code.
I would like to search events by `email:11111@example.com` which event have email field matched. but now , return results also matched `example`.

Comment: You'll need to add a logstash filter to parse that field and also probably set the proper mapping/analyzer for that field in ES. Can you show us a sample log line?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53558553/append-specific-mdc-field-into-logstash-log