# Append specific MDC field into logstash log

Tags: spring, logging, log4j, logstash, logback

I am trying add custom field into logstash appender in logback-spring.xml like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<appender name="stash" class="net.logstash.logback.appender.LogstashSocketAppender">
        <host>xx.xx.xx.xx</host>
        <port>xxxxx</port>
        <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder">
            <includeMdcKeyName>myField</includeMdcKeyName>
        </encoder>
</appender>

<root level="info">
    <appender-ref ref="stash" />
</root>

</configuration>
```

It gives me error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration error detected: 
>   ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@34:71 - no applicable action for [encoder], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][appender][encoder]]

When I tried console appender and I tried print that field like in sample below it worked.

```
<layout>
      <Pattern>%-4r [%thread] %-5level My Field: [%X{myField:--}] %msg%n</Pattern>
</layout>
```

Can you tell me what I did wrong with udp appender? Thank you in advice.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You're using an [UDP appender](https://github.com/logstash/logstash-logback-encoder#udp-appender), and it does not have an `encoder`. You should use [TCP Appender](https://github.com/logstash/logstash-logback-encoder#tcp-appenders) (`LogstashTcpSocketAppender` instead of `LogstashSocketAppender`):

```
<appender name="stash" class="net.logstash.logback.appender.LogstashTcpSocketAppender">
    <destination>xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxxx</destination>
    <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder">
        <includeMdcKeyName>myField</includeMdcKeyName>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```

---

Take a look a demo project I've created [here](https://gitlab.com/madhead-playgrounds/so53558553).

[This code](https://gitlab.com/madhead-playgrounds/so53558553/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/by/dev/madhead/playgrounds/so53558553/App.kt#L16-22) (Kotlin):

```
MDC.put("mdc", "so53558553")

LOG.warn("Warn")
```

With a [`logback-spring.xml`](https://gitlab.com/madhead-playgrounds/so53558553/blob/master/src/main/resources/logback-spring.xml#L3-8) like this:

```
<appender name="logstash" class="net.logstash.logback.appender.LogstashTcpSocketAppender">
    <destination>localhost:5000</destination>
    <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder">
        <includeMdcKeyName>mdc</includeMdcKeyName>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```

Produces such records in Logstash:

```
{
    "level_value" => 30000,
            "mdc" => "so53558553",
           "port" => 35450,
    "logger_name" => "by.dev.madhead.playgrounds.so53558553.SpringBootConsoleApplication",
           "host" => "172.17.0.1",
       "@version" => "1",
     "@timestamp" => 2018-12-03T01:16:28.793Z,
    "thread_name" => "main",
        "message" => "Warn",
          "level" => "WARN"
}
```

[image: <code>mdc</code> field]

As you see, `mdc` values are seen by Logstash as a field in the `LoggingEvent`.

**EDIT**

You may not see your field in Kibana due to an ELK misconfiguration. I'm pasting my Logstash pipiline config (`/etc/logstash/conf.d/01-input.conf`) just for the reference (it's very basic):

```
input {
    tcp {
        port => 5000
        codec => json_lines
    }
}

output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => [ "localhost:9200" ]
        index => "logback-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    }
}
```

Then I've configured logs in Kibana with `logback-*` pattern:

[image: Create index pattern-01]
[image: Create index pattern-02]

And voila:

[image: MDC fields in Kibana]

Comment: I tried it, but when I change to LogstashTcpSocketAppender no logs showed in kibana :/

Comment: That may be an ELK configuration issue.

Comment: Thank for response. Unfortunatelly I don't have access to configure our kibana so I as our devops to check it. Thank you.

Comment: @DenisStephanov have you found what the issue was?